# How to authenticate direct requests to files in a specific directory

Tags: php, security, .htaccess, wordpress

Our site is powered by Wordpress and I'm using a plugin which allows users to upload files. We have reasonable security in place to prevent malicious files from getting loaded to the server by users, but those files are then directly accessible to the public. For example, anyone  can directly access any of those files like so:

```
http://www.website.com/path/to/files/file_1.pdf
http://www.website.com/path/to/files/file_2.pdf
http://www.website.com/path/to/files/file_3.docx
```

This is a security/privacy problem because those files could contain personal data that should not be available to anyone.

I know I can block access to the entire directory using .htaccess but then the plugin will stop working. Instead, I think I need to use .htaccess to redirect those requests to a script which checks if the current user is authorized to view them. The tricky part is that direct requests to those files bypass the Wordpress app, so none of the core functions (like `is_user_logged_in()`) are available if I redirect to some intermediary page.

It seems like I either need to write a script to check for the Wordpress authorization cookies manually (which sounds like a huge hassle) or somehow loop in Wordpress.

Any suggestions for an elegant way to add this security layer without breaking the plugin?

Comment: Could you set a session variable to specify that the user can access the file, then in the intermediate page you just have to read the session variable?

Comment: That sounds very interesting. Could you elaborate a bit? Perhaps as an answer.

Comment: @Boundless I think I understand the part about setting the session variable and then checking for that in the intermediate page. I'm not sure what that script should do if the appropriate authorization is established. Should it end with a redirect to the original file using `headers(Location: ... )`?

Comment: You might be able to simply block access to the file in .htaccess in that folder, and allow it thru a plugin like filebase.

Comment: Similar to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13872/how-to-restrict-access-to-uploaded-files